# Programmatically starting a jQuery UI sortable drag ? - Issues with IE8 compatibility

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI Sortable behavior and have come upon a situation in which I needed to start the sortable drag behavior from interaction with another element other than the original handle (which is not visible at the time).
I have managed to put together a way to achieve this thanks to suggestions in some posts and the use of [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js) (used to run official jQUI tests) and I can procedurally start the sortable drag process in pretty much all browsers except IE8 and below, simulating the events like so:

`item.simulate('mousedown',pos).simulate('mousemove',{ clientX: pos.clientX+1, clientY: pos.clientY});`

**Problem:** In IE8 (or below), after the interaction with the outside 'handle' and simulation of  mousedown and mousemove events, the drag is indeed correctly started, but as soon as the user really moves his mouse in any way/shape/form, the drag stops or cancels as if the 'mouseup' event had ocurred to finalize it.
I highly think this is due to some fundamental difference in the old fireEvent (IE8-) method vs the dispatchEvent that everything else uses, but cannot quite figure out how to, or if it's possible to prevent it.

What I'm looking for are snippets of what may be done to correct this or suggestions as to why this is happening and if it can have a workaround of some sort to prevent the cancelling (such as is the behavior that occurs in any other browser using dispatchEvent instead of fireEvent).

Have put together a small example for you of the success (any recent browser) or failure of the situation described: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38ndq/3/)

**TL;DR**: Have put together a small way to procedurally start a jQUI sortable drag (through jquery.simulate.js, link above), but it fails to work or cancels itself in IE8-. Need some guidance or suggestions about how to overcome that. Check above demo